# Can I use %category% like Templates in my Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, urls

I have seen that Wordpress uses `%category%` like strings to create url templates. Is there an easy way to allow such mechanism in a plugin? For example in the plugin's settings page user specifies an option

```
`<a href=%my_url%>Click here</a>`
```

And in my plugin I replace `%my_url%` with an actual URL before `echo`ing it.

Is there a function/mechanism in wordpress that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything WordPress specific here. Use PHP's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace tokens entered by users in the settings. In your plugin code, wherever you are echoing the setting value wrap it in str_replace with the value you want to replace %my_url% with.

```
echo str_replace("%my_url%", $real_url_value, $setting_text);
```